# Receiving blank line from Client

Tags: java, c++, networking

I have a C++ client and a Java Server. I'm simply trying to send a string "Test" from the client. Here's my relevant JAVA code,

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Recieved Something. " + line.length());
                System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Here's my output (There's a blank line after Received Something)

```
Recieved Something. 0

Recieved Something. 0
```

And the C++ Code (not entirely sure what you guys need as I'm new to C++

```
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }


    struct hostent *host;
    if((host=gethostbyname("localhost"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to resolve hostname.\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port= htons(2501);
    SockAddr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr= *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr))!=0)
    {
        printf("Failed to establish connection with server\r\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
   string toSend = "Test\n";
    send(Socket,toSend.c_str(), strlen(toSend.c_str()), 0);
```

So why am I not receiving the Test String?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the line varible some value.

use

```
 while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: O wow just saw that.. I've done this a thousand times java side.

Answer (score 1):

You do not save the result of `readLine` anywhere. You might want to assign it to the `line`variable.